# I/O error in database restore

Tags: sql-server-2005

I am getting the below error while I am trying to do a restore. Can you please suggest a fix?

> Backup,Unknown,During restore restart an I/O error occurred on checkpoint file 'd:\dwd\smot\res.CKP' (operating system error 3(The system cannot find the path specified.)). The statement is proceeding but cannot be restarted. Ensure that a valid storage location exists for the checkpoint file.
>
> Backup,Unknown,Error: 18272 Severity: 16 State: 1.

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like one of these scenarios:

- The file isn't at 'd:\dwd\smot\res.CKP'
- The file is there but the process that is attempting to restore it does not have read permissions.
- The file is there and the permission are good, but the file is corrupt.

Comment: The fix for #2 is obvious, but is there a way s/he could create (or re-create, if corrupt) the checkpoint file - preferably non-destructively?

Comment: I was hoping the original poster would give us some insight into which it was.  Unfortunately if it's #3, s/he is most likely out of luck.  The only way to fix the issue is to create another backup file / checkpoint file.  And the only way to do so that I'm aware of is to have the original database up and running.  Of course, if you're trying to restore from a file, that usually means that the original database isn't available.